# solrj can not boost results

Tags: java, solr, solrj

I am new to solr . I tried to boost result by applying query

```
query.set("bq", "id:"
+ userId + "^100");
```

When I execute query it didn't boost result. Where I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are missing defType as edismax

```
   query.set("defType", "edismax");
   query.set("bq", "id:" + userId + "^100");
```

Hope so it will help you..